# Jenkins Archiving fails says :"You have to provide a value for either the marketing or technical version. Found neither."

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins

I am trying to build Xcode project in Jenkins, I was able to successfully run my first Jenkins project. After compilation it gave me "app" bundle.

Now i'm trying to archive the bundle, but I'm getting the following error

"You have to provide a value for either the marketing or technical version. Found neither."

I tried playing with configuration but nothing seems to be working.
[image: Configurations (already tried with empty fields)]

Comment: you got any solution?

Comment: Yup, writing down the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode has a built-in tool called [agvtool](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/agvtool.1.html). Agvtool only works if you have "Apple generic" version system in settings.

Change the version system to "Apple generic" in target settings.
[image: Target settings]

Comment: I have selected Versioning system as Aple Generic still getting same error

Comment: Jenkins console out put : [ios] $ /usr/bin/xcodebuild -version
Xcode 8.2.1
Build version 8C1002
Fetching marketing version number (CFBundleShortVersionString) from project.
[ios] $ /usr/bin/agvtool mvers -terse1
Found marketing version (CFBundleShortVersionString): DevOps_ios_build-81.
Marketing version (CFBundleShortVersionString) found in project configuration: DevOps_ios_build-81.
Fetching technical version number (CFBundleVersion) from project.
[ios] $ /usr/bin/agvtool vers -terse
No marketing version found (CFBundleVersion)

Comment: Technical version (CFBundleVersion) found in project configuration: .
Updating marketing version (CFBundleShortVersionString) to: DevOps_ios_build-82
[ios] $ /usr/bin/agvtool new-marketing-version DevOps_ios_build-82
Setting CFBundleShortVersionString of project PatientPortal to: 
    DevOps_ios_build-82.

Updating CFBundleShortVersionString in Info.plist(s)...

Comment: Updated CFBundleShortVersionString in "PatientPortal.xcodeproj/../PatientPortal/PatientPortal-Info.plist" to DevOps_ios_build-82
Updating technical version (CFBundleVersion) to: DevOps_ios_build-82
[ios] $ /usr/bin/agvtool new-version -all DevOps_ios_build-82
Setting version of project PatientPortal to: 
    DevOps_ios_build-82.

Also setting CFBundleVersion key (assuming it exists)

Updating CFBundleVersion in Info.plist(s)...

Updated CFBundleVersion in "PatientPortal.xcodeproj/../PatientPortal/PatientPortal-Info.plist" to DevOps_ios_build-82

Comment: Marketing version (CFBundleShortVersionString) used by Jenkins to produce the IPA: DevOps_ios_build-82
Technical version (CFBundleVersion) used by Jenkins to produce the IPA: DevOps_ios_build-82

Comment: Jenkins error : 
** ARCHIVE SUCCEEDED **
Cleaning up previously generated .ipa files
Cleaning up previously generated .dSYM.zip files
Packaging IPA
[ios] $ /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print :ApplicationProperties:CFBundleVersion" /Users/Compumatrice/Jenkins/Home/workspace/DevOps_ios_build/build/Pods-PatientPortal.xcarchive/Info.plist
[ios] $ /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print :ApplicationProperties:CFBundleShortVersionString" /Users/Compumatrice/Jenkins/Home/workspace/DevOps_ios_build/build/Pods-PatientPortal.xcarchive/Info.plist

Comment: You have to provide a value for either the marketing or technical version. Found neither.
Build step 'Xcode' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE